# check url if string json found do action flutter

Tags: json, flutter

check url json id

```
[{"id":"1859525"}]
```

if id content number do

```
  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => FourthRoute(
                category: post,
                accountLogin: accountLogin,
                account: currentAccountProfile)));
```

post here is 1859525

use if id found at url do it once after app open

and remember that id it's already open don't open it again

that's possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
SharedPreferences _prefs;

   _saveId(String id) async {
    if (_prefs == null) _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    if (id != null) {
      // you can decide whether allowing saving a null value is appropiate for your use case it is equivalant to erasing the key value pair
      final userData = json.encode(
        {
          'id': id,
        },
      );
      _prefs.setString('userKey', userData);
    }
  }

  _getId() async {
    if (_prefs == null) _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if(_prefs.containsKey('userKey')){
      final Map<String, dynamic> extractedUserData =
          json.decode(_prefs.getString('userKey')) as Map<String, Object>;

      String id = extractedUserData['id'];
    }else{
      //no id saved
    }
  }
```

then when you get the id back you could do the check you want


This is the general idea how to save and load data using `SharedPreferences` [here](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) is a link to install the dependencies

Comment: it's will remember that id opened before ??  where to set url !

Comment: no your question was a little unclear can you clarify what you want.

Comment: i need to check url and get id number , if found  do Navigator to open anther page and do it once meaning remember that id don't open it again

Comment: since I dont know the exact set up of what your doing I geuss you would save the ids  to your backend then check against them as needed. Or you can use ```SharedPreferences``` if you need to persist the id  locally.